# Problems displaying barcode font

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, barcode

I am creating labels with bar codes EAN13.
I do not want to use the barcode4j lib for reasons of processing speed.
Using iReport I added the font FF EAN, and a custom function for the barcode translation.
Because I run the report in java (in eclipse ide), I exported the font in a jar file, and I added it into my java project.
Using the PDF preview iReport barcode can be seen properly, but running it in java barcodes are not displayed.
The font exporting procedure runs well, because I had already integrated the font Times New Roman, not available by default.
Why the font FF EAN is ignored?

Comment: Please help me..! TTF Font file is avaiable here: http://ambizioso.altervista.org/files/FF_EAN13.zip

Comment: I brilliantly solved by using another solution. thanks for your support!

Comment: You should write how you did it.